# How to power on linux pc using locally connected pc

Tags: linux, windows, lan, power

i need to **poweron**  windows pc using locally connected another pc(lan),

**windows pc ip addr ==> 192.168.1.10**

**locally connected pc ==> 192.168.1.20**

Suggest me, how do i do that.

Comment: Search for "Wake On Lan"

Answer (score 3):

Follow [this webpage](http://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/) for more information.

Here are the steps:

1. Enable Wake-on LAN in BIOS
2. Enable Wake-on LAN in operating system
3. Send the packet using application attached in webpage